# How do I use a local IDE for Java Transforms in Foundry Code Repositories?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a Java Transforms Code Repository. What are the steps required to use a local IDE, like IntelliJ, to write code and publish into the Foundry Code Repository?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your repository is upgraded to the latest language version. Then in your Code repository’s Authoring display:

- Click the “Clone” button and copy the Stemma URI

On your local machine:

- Run `git clone <URI>` on your local machine
- Run `./gradleww idea`